# Weißrussland vs. Belarus

Tags: proper-noun, place-name, evolution

Throughout my life I only heard the term "Weißrussland" for the country in Eastern Europe. I knew that the former GDR used a different term and I learned the English word Belarus, but I never saw these words used in Germany.

Now, in the last weeks, I noticed that most newspapers use the term "Belarus" to refer to Weißrussland.

When (and why) did this change happen?

Comment: Du kannst hier auch auf deutsch fragen, wenn Du magst.

Comment: Danke, was ist denn bevorzugt?

Comment: It's a political game to play a nationalist card: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wei%C3%9Frussland#Name

Comment: In der deutschen Sprache ist (seit 150 Jahren?) "Weißrussland" verankert, so wie England uns nicht "Doytshlund" nennt sondern Germany. Politisch motivierte Umbenennungen sind da oft nur aufgesetzt.

Comment: @JFabianMeier: Es gibt keine Präferenzen. Die Antwortsprache folgt der Fragesprache - in den Grenzen Deutsch & Englisch. Die Frage sollte so sein, dass Du weißt was Du schreibst - und verstehst was zurück kommt :)

Comment: @JFabianMeier: Bezüglich der bevorzugten Sprache gibt es hier unterschiedliche Meinungen. Einigkeit besteht aber darüber, dass Antworten und Kommentare wenn möglich in derselben Sprache gepostet werden sollen in der die Frage verfasst worden ist. Hier sind ein paar Fakten: Das Thema dieses Forums ist die deutsche Sprache. Jeder der hierher kommt interessiert sich dafür. Aber nicht jeder, der hierher kommt spricht Englisch oder interessiert sich dafür. ...

Comment: ... Auch Russen, Araber, Chinesen usw. wollen dieses Forum nutzen um Deutsch zu lernen, und es wäre absurd, ihnen abzuverlangen, Englisch zu beherrschen wenn sie Deutsch lernen wollen. Ein weiterer Punkt: ca. 95% aller hier gestellten Fragen werden von Menschen beantwortet, deren Muttersprache Deutsch ist. Wenn dann jemand, dessen Muttersprache ebenfalls Deutsch ist, eine Frage auf Englisch stellt, entsteht die absurde Situation, dass sich deutsche Muttersprachler über ihre Muttersprache in einer Fremdsprache unterhalten. ...

Comment: ... Mein Vorschlag lautet daher, solche Absurditäten zu vermeiden und Fragen in der jeweiligen Muttersprache zu stellen wenn diese Englisch oder Deutsch ist. Menschen mit anderer Muttersprache sollten von diesen beiden Sprachen jene wählen, die sie besser beherrschen.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: Einigkeit besteht darüber nicht aber es ist die Mehrheitsmeinung derer, die sich dazu hier, bzw. auf Meta geäußert haben.

Comment: There are a couple of texts available on the internet that address the issue: https://www.n-tv.de/politik/Warum-nun-von-Belarus-die-Rede-ist-article21962955.html

Comment: German Foreign Ministery speaks of Belarus: https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/aussenpolitik/laender/belarus-node

Comment: Also, the discussion page of said Wikipedia entry: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diskussion:Wei%C3%9Frussland#Warum_hei%C3%9Ft_der_Artikel_immer_noch_Wei%C3%9Frussland?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

User [Olafant](https://german.stackexchange.com/users/36196/olafant) found [this news](https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/sagen-meinen-weissrussland-oder-belarus.2907.de.html?dram:article_id=481876) at Deutschlandfunk (DLF), dating on 6th August 2020. There it is claimed that "Weißrussland" is in (diplomatic) use since 1991 (= the end of the soviet union) by Germany. And some year later the Auswärtige Amt (foreign affairs) switched to "Belarus" like Switzerland and Austria did already. A [news by n-tv](https://www.n-tv.de/politik/Warum-nun-von-Belarus-die-Rede-ist-article21962955.html) adds that in January 2020 [the Belarusisch-Deutsche Geschichtskommission](https://www.dgo-online.org/neuigkeiten/aktuelles/belarusisch-deutsche-geschichtskommission-gegruendet/) was founded to propose the use of "Belarus". This organization is part of the older "Deutsche Gesellschaft für Osteuropakunde e.V.". DLF continues that in April 2020 news agencies like Deutsche Presse-Agentur (dpa) switched from Weißrussland to Belarus.

Be aware that many newspapers reprint/use dpa news, so *I assume* other news *had* to follow because the often reprint dpa articles and readers might think this is another country.

Quote about the name itself from DLF:

> Der deutsche Begriff „Weißrussland“ ist aber keine Eins-zu-eins-Übersetzung von „Belarus“, auch wenn er so klingen mag: Zwar bedeutet „Bela“ tatsächlich weiß, der Begriff „Rus“ aber bezieht sich nicht auf Russland, sondern auf die sogenannte Kiewer Rus – ein Großreich im Mittelalter. Das gilt zwar als Vorläufer der heutigen Staaten Belarus, Russland und Ukraine, ist aber eben nicht synonym mit Russland. Deswegen würde „Weißrussland“ auf Russisch nicht Belarus heißen, sondern „Belarossija“.

Together with [news by n-tv](https://www.n-tv.de/politik/Warum-nun-von-Belarus-die-Rede-ist-article21962955.html), dating on 10th August 2020, the core in my translation:

- bela = white in russian,
- rus = historical area as naming somewhat the origin of the rus' people - the [Kievan Rus'](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/da/KiewerRus.jpg)(map image from wiki)

  - three capitals Kiev (Ukraine) & Minsk (Belarus) & Moscow (Russia) locate in the historic area
  - so Belarus put the logic that "Russ" like in "Weißrussland" is not "Rus" like in "Kiewer Rus" which they refer to
- which together is *not* "white russia", that would be "Belarossija".

  - note: that would be the transcript in Russian, the second official language after Belarusian.
- the name "Weißrussland" was established in the 19th century
- the name "Weißruthenien" was a logical translation before the Nazis and not usable again since the Nazis used it for their conquered areas (see e.g. [Online-Lexikon zur Kultur und Geschichte der Deutschen im östlichen Europa](https://ome-lexikon.uni-oldenburg.de/laender/weissrussland))

One thing is  - until now - leftover: "[belarussisch](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/belarussisch)" (duden) mixes the russian part in, from the logical point it would be "belarusisch". The (linked above) Online-Lexikon also put it into question wether Russia is by name the only originating country from the Kievan Rus'. And if a country can enforce a translation of its name in another country.

**So the answer is:**

- "Weißrussland" is considered wrong from the beginning (by the current country Belarus)

  - and it was used in Germany not later than 1991 for diplomatic correspondence
- "Belarus" is considered official and refers the origin of [Kievan Rus'](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kievan_Rus%27) or Kyivan Rus (wiki)
- news agencies started in April 2020 to use "Belarus"

Other sources about the now former use of any name regarding this country now called Belarus are books mentioned on [wiki](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wei%C3%9Frussland#cite_note-10) - because more names than "Weißrussland" have been used

- Diana Siebert: Bäuerliche Alltagsstrategien in der Belarussischen SSR (1921–1941) (= Quellen und Studien zur Geschichte des östlichen Europa. Band 52). Franz Steiner Verlag, Stuttgart 1998, S. 24, Anm. 34.
- Vgl. Alexander Brakel: Unter Rotem Stern und Hakenkreuz. Baranowicze 1939 bis 1944. Das westliche Weißrussland unter sowjetischer und deutscher Besatzung (= Zeitalter der Weltkriege. Band 5). Ferdinand Schöningh Verlag, Paderborn u. a. 2009, ISBN 978-3-506-76784-4, S. 31.

Comment: Wie wäre es, den link zu n-tv durch einen auf [deutschlandfunk.de](https://www.deutschlandfunk.de/sagen-meinen-weissrussland-oder-belarus.2907.de.html?dram:article_id=481876) zu ersetzen? Möglicherweise betrachtet @FadedGiant das (so wie ich) eher als *reputable source*? ;)

Comment: @Olafant: Danke für den Link, da ist ein kompakteres Zitat drin :). Außerdem zeigen die Diskussionen in der dt. wiki von August 2018, dass die diplomatische Umbenennung deutlich vor 2020 stattfand. Nur in der Presse nicht - worauf die Frage zielt. Bei N-tv wird die DOG-Untergesellschaft erwähnt, drum lass ich das drin.

Comment: I don't really see the problem with "Weißrussland" from a logical viewpoint. "Russland" is derived from "Rus", and if "Rus" = "Russland", then "Bela Rus" = "Weißrussland" sounds perfectly fine to me. I don't see why the russian spelling should come into this.

Comment: @Lykanion: well, it is the country Belarus that says "that is not logical because we are the Rus not the Russ (and we are independent from Russia)." I for myself see pros and cons in a translated word like Weißrussland - e.g. I cannot pronounce belarus wrong to belarusian ears. And the best case the same name describes the same time period where the governmental system was the same.

Comment: Ich halte Begründungen mit Verweisen auf vermeintlich falsche Übersetzungen für grundfalsch, denn sie sind überhaupt nicht verallgemeinerbar. Im Deutschen sagen wir *Deutschland* und *Frankreich*, im Englischen aber darum nicht *German Land* und *Franc Empire*. Das *Poland* im Englischen wird nicht zu *Polenland* im Deutschen. Das russische *Rossija* nennen wir Deutschen nicht *Russien*. *Japan* nennen wir nicht *Sonnenursprung* und so weiter und so fort. Daher sehe ich nicht ein, wieso wir nicht *Weißrussland* zu einem Land sagen sollen, das andere Sprachen eben *Belarus* nennen.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: da bin ich grundsätzlich dabei, jedes Land hat seine eigene Sprache und trifft weitestgehend seine eigene Entscheidung, wie es andere Länder nennt - mit irgendeiner Orientierung am Original. Ansonsten gäbe es für alte Städte wie Köln auch nur 1 Begriff - leider ist der recht neu und die anderen Sprachen haben sich einfach nicht angepasst^^ (es nützt mir nur nix, weil meine Meinung da nicht gefragt wurde, sondern die weißrussische)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm, ich weiß, dass Sie dafür nichts können. Daher würde ich die Antwort auch nicht abwerten. Aber meinen Einwand finde ich wichtig, damit jeder rational entscheiden kann, wie er das Land in Zukunft nennt.

Comment: @BjörnFriedrich: okay, jetzt komme ich ins Straucheln: meine Antwort hatte ich heute geändert auf "Belarus sagt, Weißrussland sei falsch" - erwecke ich noch den Eindruck, dass andere auch der Meinung sind? (ich seh dann wohl den Wald vor Bäumen nicht)

Comment: Also dem muss ich widersprechen; Weißrussland ist das übliche Wort und wird in deutschen, österreichischen und schweizerischen Medien auch so genannt, und zwar „schon immer“.

Comment: @mike: welche Quellen gibt es für "schon immer"? m.E. ist es in der Diplomatie seit ~ 10 Jahren anders, und vor dem zweiten Weltkrieg auch nicht einheitlich. Neben einer Kommentar-"Antwort" bleibt die eigene Recherche mit eigener Antwort die beste Möglichkeit auf eine fundierte Antwort.

Answer (score 3):

Shegit has already explained why *Weißrussland* is not the right translation for Belarus. But there is another explanation as to why you should use *Belarus* instead of *Weißrussland*. And is due to its history and national identity.

[Quoting Sven Gerst](https://www.zdf.de/nachrichten/politik/weissrussland-bezeichnung-belarus-100.html) (interviewed by ZDF Heute)

> Das Land war in seiner Geschichte immer Teil größerer Regionalmächte. Spricht man von 'Weißrussland', klingt das immer noch so, als wäre das Land irgendwie ein Teil von Russland. Das sei für viele Belarusen problematisch, die sich nie auf Identitätsfindung hätten begeben können.
>
> Deshalb ist es gerade jetzt, wo das Land zum ersten Mal im Zentrum der Weltöffentlichkeit steht, für viele Belarusen schwer erträglich, wenn ihr Land 'Weißrussland' genannt wird. Belarusen sind ja keine Russen. Sie haben ihre eigene Identität.

> In its history, the country has always been part of larger regional powers. When you talk about 'Belarus', it still sounds like the country is somehow part of Russia. This is problematic for many Belarusians who have never been able to go about finding their identity.
>
> Therefore, especially now that the country is in the center of the world for the first time, many Belarusians find it difficult to bear when their country is called 'Weissrussland'. Belarusians are not Russians. They have their own identity.

For these reasons (and the flawed translation), institutions like the belarusisch-deutsche Geschichtskommission recommends using the term Belarus. A recommendation that was followed first by politics and now by the media.

Comment: The funny part with "own identity" is for me, that the russians and the belarusians and the ukranians refer all three back to the Kievan Rus' ... - maybe for different time periods, still the Kievan Rus'. So, yes, I find it confusing as I'm living far far away and are not used to understand the finer distinctions.

Comment: Und Angelsachsen klingt, als seien die ein Teil von Sachsen? "Bela" heißt ja immer noch "Weiß", ein Land ist es auch noch und der Zusatz gibt ja eigentlich recht deutlich Hinweis, dass es eben ein eigenständiges Land ist.